# Android 2.2 phone as "mouse" for Windows

Tags: android

I'd like to create an application that utilizes touch-screen as a "pad". There will be 3 small buttons in the bottom area of touch-screen, and the rest will be used a mouse movement area. 
The first button will act as "left-click" in real mouse, the second one will act as "scroll", and the last one as "right-click"
When a user make any movement (event "move", "up" , "down" or "cancel") in that area, the real mouse-pointer in Windows Desktop will also move.
Transmission media will be Bluetooth and Wifi.

so, here's some questions :
1). is it possible to utilize multi-touch in Froyo ? Example for this case is when user want to "block" some text. In real mouse, we just hold left-click and then drag the pointer. In android, this will be touching the first button while at the same time, touching the "pad" area and make some movement.

2). How can I turn this application concept into a real application ? ( general idea or algorithms )

Comment: Froyo supports the multi-touch. Question should be, whether your device (hardware) supports it or not?

Comment: @Mudassir -- I'm planning to use Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 as primary device... Does it support Multi-Touch ?

Comment: As I've red in its specs, Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 supports multi-touch. But you should better make sure from the official site for your home country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out RemoteDroid. It's an open-source app which has most of the functionality you described.
http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/

Answer (score 0):

An app like this is going to have two main parts. An Android app which generates a series of movement vectors or movement data, and a program on your target operating system which receives this data and translates it into a software mouse. You will also need the bluetooth stack's necessary for that transfer (I get the feeling wifi won't give you the responsiveness you want without some serious optimization)

When it comes to the Android side of matters, I think you'll need to experiment in the best way to capture those mouse movements. I'd think a speed-vector structure might be your best bet, and it seems most similar to what I know of Mouse Movements.